# OS X Yosemite takes ages to restore

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, restore

I have bought MacBook Pro with OS X Yosemite two days ago. After I transferred my files through Windows sharing I come to know that Disk utility didn't install properly as it says damaged or incomplete. So I had to restore is as new.

First time it took more than 8 hrs because I slept after 5 hrs of wait. 
Then again I had to repair because I didn't find iMovie, iPhoto etc because it was in purchased items in iTunes but it also take ages and also I stopped migration through apple app because of same problem, took ages.

So I was afraid if data was saved somewhere so I restored again. I started at 3pm and it's 6.46 and it's not even half of it and saying 33 hours left. I followed Youtube videos, they says their repair takes just half an hour! Need help in a detailed and easy way. What does it mean by boot?

Comment: the problem is apple store is not in my city and i asked them they said it will take 2 days and money too!

Comment: i want to know why it takes 8 8 hours or more than this?is it just with me?

Answer (score 2):

there might be a better solution (below), but a slow internet is a slow internet.  it will just be a less painful download.  read the steps to see what you think and if it works for you.

- so boot into the ailing os
- if you don't have the yosemite installer, download  via the app store.  yes this might still be slow, but should be resumable and you can do other things while it goes.
- download disk maker x, this is a prog that takes and osx installer app and makes an installer usb stick with the full os  on it.
- run diskmaker x and get an 8 gb usb stick and point it to the yosemite installer.  be careful you choose the right disk to erase.
- then just boot off the usb stick and it will install from the local installer files.

i use this program and depend on it to make installers for various machines

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advice you to visit the apple store for them to fix your Mac.

But if you insist doing it your self:

Turn off your mac.

Hold the <kbd>cmd</kbd> and the <kbd>r</kbd> and turn the Mac on by pressing the power button. (keep holding the cmd+r.)

Now you will get this:

[image: restore]

First Run the Disk Utility application to Repair your disk. (**do not Erase anything**).

Next run the Reinstall OS X.

If you deleted the recovery for some reason, you need to use the Internet recovery to get it:

Immediately after hearing the Mac boot chime, hold down Command+Option+R – if you see the Apple logo you waited too long and need to reboot and try again.

You should now have a working Yosemite after waiting minimum a hour or much more depending on you Internet speed.

If you have erased Apple applications like iTunes ect.. then follow this instructions how to get them back. [OS X Yosemite: Reinstall apps that came with your Mac](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH18868?viewlocale=en_US)

Finally back to transferring: How to transfer files from Windows PC to Mac.

Read and follow instructions from here. [OS X Yosemite: Transfer your info from a computer.](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH18870?viewlocale=en_US)

Comment: i have done all this but after that i mean in reinstalling process its taking time. but i erased disk utility. why u said not to erase?

Comment: Disk-Utility is a application, not a folder. If you used the ERASE the disk, than all your information has been erased from the disk. That was a big mistake! Now you have to start all over with installing everything that is why it asks you about itunes and iphoto. Those applications were per-installed on your computer by Apple and you deleted them. Seriously, get some help, we can not solve this online.

Comment: We need to come clean here: you did not erase the disk utility (it is a application), you erased the disk it self using the disk utility to do so.

Comment: ok yh i erased cos it wast working it was damaged.and every video on youtube says to erase so i did.

Comment: well since you erased all from your disk now you have to reinstall all of it using the Internet. For example the Yosemite it self could take anywhere from a 1 hour to several hours (depending on your Internet speed), then you need to get all of the Apple applications as well (like iTunes and so on), that could take additional hours to do. Good luck and follow my instructions, and before you delete anything come here and ask.

Comment: i appreciate ur help i made an account here  will definantly come here.i i wish i had apple store in my city .normally they says it takes just 24 to 30 minutes.

Comment: i made a video on youtube plz have a look so probably u will understand and also should i install yosemite app from app store (which i canceled) for imovie etc? here is the youtube link http://youtu.be/yg65PGqkp-E

Comment: Thanks, that video say your are downloading Yosemite and other apple components from Internet. Since you used the disk utility application and Erased all from your hard drive (disk) it has to now get it. It is downloading about 6-10 GB (gigabyte) of data (huge). I do not know your Internet speed, but I have a very fast one and it would take me more than 2 hours.If you have normal household connection (1500 mbps) it can take anywhere from 8 hours and more. Yours indicates you have about 500 mbps speed, that is why 20 hours.

Comment: You can Cancel that and start over to see if it now goes faster, but I recommend you start that process late night to get better speed. Yes you need to download Yosemite from the Internet, since you deleted yours.

Comment: oh thank u so much.thats what i wanted to know.but one thing i didnt understand on youtube everyone erased their disk utility and reinstall then it took for them just 24 to 30 min..and i followed excatly like then....

Comment: They did not erase the Disk utility, they erased the disk, which is not the same even the name says almost the same. Disk Utility is a application (a program) that is used to repair the storage disk or to erase the storage disk.

Comment: as final lesson, DO NOT ERASE your disk until: you can not repair it with the Disk utility or the cmd+r does not work any more, or nothing works at all. Finally, if i have answered your question mark it as done so we can move on.

Comment: i have done restore again.it took again more than 8 hours anyway but it didn't reach in middle suddenly it restarting mac and every thing goes fine. I went to app store to download os x yosemite it says like before u already have it in ur mac i click on start download then i came to know its same procedure and will again took same timing again i stopped it and start downloading iMovie iphoto etc which was in App Store purchased item and free.i came to know that it won't come with yosemite app.apple downloaded them in same way from App Store.

Comment: i want to know is this safe now after reinstalling and stopped instaltion so many time?i mean i am afraid if data is stored somewhere in mac where i can't reach?like before reinstallation i saved few sites in bookmark then twice i erased Disk Utility and reinstall how is it possible that its still saved when i erased everything ?!or its saves in apple accounts? so i own have to give applestore now?cos its working fine now.plz reply

Comment: What are you dong?  once it restated and everything was working, WHY do you go to the apple store and want to download it again, it even tells you you already have the Yosemite. Since you made the big mistake to erase everything on your disk, you data are no longer there, so you have to transfer them again. Sorry I can not help you further.